# Need to proxy to dynamic ports

Tags: linux, proxy, apache2, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I use the gameserver panel pterodactyl.io. There I want to host Sinusbot, which has a web interface. Of course, all servers have different ports, and every new server gets another port. I'd like to redirect URLs like:
https://example.com/1234 to http://localhost:1234. Unfortunately, I have no idea how I can realize this with apache2 -.-

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=redirect+urls+to+localhost+apache+2

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Do you need help with all the configurations (how to set static reverse proxy) or just need configuration for dynamic ports?

Comment: You can write a bash script that will update your vhost file everytime you create new server . And then bash will reload the vhost file in apache2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually quite simple with mod_rewrite

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^/?(\d+)$ http://localhost:$1/ [P]

Header edit Location http://localhost:(\d)/(.*) http://example.com/$1/$2
```

Comment: thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. somehow I did not find anything by googling :D